# Azure Data Factory, sink column name has spaces

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to derive one column in ADF Data Flow, the source and sink table is the same. Some columns have spaces in their names. I'm getting and error while mapping them.

> Column name cannot contain special characters or spaces when using
> Azure Synapse Analytics or Parquet format in 'Table'

Is there any option to solve it and load the data, without changing the column name?

[image: how to solve it?]

Answer (score 0):

Parquet format does not allow spaces in column names

Comment: That is not the answer...

Comment: That is actually literally what the error message is telling you.